# Silence the warning: `Non-conforming tab character` in gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I usually run my code with `ifort`, but during implementation, I prefer compiling and testing with `gfortran` as I find it to be a lot stricter than its intel counterpart.

While turning on compiling options such as `-Wall`, I get the following warning:

`Warning: Nonconforming tab character at (1)`

Is there a way to silence this one particular warning while using the same compiling options? Note that I do **NOT** want to replace tabs with space characters. If there is no way to resolve this issue, then the answer "No it's not possible" would suffice.

Comment: `| grep -v "Nonconforming tab character"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Warning***: the below answer I originally wrote only applies to gfortran 4.x. The behaviour has been reversed in version 5.x, see [the answer by DrOli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36242012/5067311).

---

What have you tried so far? Does `-Wtabs` help? From `man gfortran`:

> -Wtabs
>
> > By default, tabs are accepted as whitespace, but tabs are not members of the Fortran Character Set.  For continuation lines, a tab followed by a digit between 1 and 9 is supported.  -Wno-tabs
> >                will cause a warning to be issued if a tab is encountered. Note, -Wno-tabs is active for -pedantic, -std=f95, -std=f2003, -std=f2008 and -Wall.

And `-Wall` sets `-Wno-tabs`.

If it doesn't help, it could still be that `-Wall` overwrites this option. Then you can try manually setting `-Wall` without the tabs part:

> -Wall
>
> > Enables commonly used warning options pertaining to usage that we recommend avoiding and that we believe are easy to avoid.  This currently includes -Waliasing, -Wampersand, -Wconversion,
> >                -Wsurprising, -Wc-binding-type, -Wintrinsics-std, -Wno-tabs, -Wintrinsic-shadow, -Wline-truncation, -Wtarget-lifetime, -Wreal-q-constant and -Wunused.

Comment: Adding a bit to your answer, `-Wall` does not overwrite the `-Wtabs` options, but `-pedantic` does.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback:) This is actually what I would expect from `pedantic`: you use it to force standard behaviour, so it should not allow tabs.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: With GCC/gFortran 5xx (I noticed with 5.3.0), the -Wtabs usage has been "reversed", and as they say, "made more sensible".

See here (https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html)

Now -Wtabs DOES give the nonconforming warning, whereas -Wno-tabs TURNS OFF the warning (i.e. the opposite of the previous usage).

Comment: Wow, interesting turn of events:) Kudos for the find, I edited my answer to note that it only works up till 4.x and that 5.x is covered by your answer. Feel free to leave a comment on the partially incorrect answer next time, it's important to know the limitations of each answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of getting rid of the warning in gfortran versions 4.x is to overwrite the -Wno-tabs flag that the -Wall flag sets. So first include -Wall and then -Wtabs

```
-Wall -Wtabs
```